Unable to Retrieve Real-Time Data from Masimo MightySat Pulse Oximeter
I am attempting to connect my Flutter app to a Masimo MightySat pulse oximeter using the flutter_blue_plus library. I can successfully connect to the device, discover services, and view characteristics, but I am not able to receive any real-time data (e.g., pulse rate, SpO₂, and other metrics) when subscribing to the available characteristics.
The MediM Health app demonstrates that it’s possible to receive real-time data from the device immediately upon connection, so I believe the issue is related to how data is accessed via flutter_blue_plus in my implementation.
Although I successfully connect to the Masimo MightySat device and see the list of services and characteristics, no data is available when subscribing to them.
I am not receiving any updates for the pulse rate, SpO₂, or other metrics.
The MediM Health app can display real-time data from the MightySat device immediately after connection, so I know the device supports this.
I suspect this might be related to the correct characteristic UUIDs or configuration settings specific to the MightySat.
I'm using Flutter Blue Plus example app. I can see every service and characteristic but after subscribe I don't have data, the MediM Health app always have real-time data after connect.
What can I do?
I really need to implement getting data from that pulse oximeter in my Flutter app. I think using the example of Flutter Blue Plus is the best way to have information about working that device with my phone, with Flutter.
I just want to know what can I change in FBP example code, to have data. Even not how change but just what can I do. It is odd that FBP can see services and characters but doesn't have data from subscription. I don't know where can I find help.
One more curious thing. I was trying that Android app: https://github.com/weliem/blessed-android/blob/master/README.md
and I only had data when I inserted and removed my finger - I didn't have it real time, as it is in the MediM Health app.
I'm attaching screenshot from my phone in Flutter Blue Plus example app after connect to Masimo:

I was tried 2 other android apps: nRF Connect and BLE Scanner and in both apps I can see the services, but the lack of runoff data in them on a regular basis, is how it is in the MediM Health app:


It would be good if you could edit the question with the service and characteristic UUIDs that are discovered. It will help identify if they are Bluetooth SIG adopted and documented at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/ or if they are custom UUIDs created by the manufacturer. Using a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool such as nRF Connect can also be helpful to understand the data.

@ukBaz thank you for your interest, I have edited the post

PLX Continuous Measurement (0x2A5F) characteristic isn't listed so I suspect this manufacturer is using their custom service and custom characteristic for this. You will need to consult the manufacturers documentation on how to get that data.
